# How to use JQuery Keyframes with Webpack/React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, keyframe

I am a bit new to website hosting. I am currently running a locally hosted page that runs with webpack. I am running this server with react as well. Thus far when I required the usage of something such as JQuery, React, or other plugins, I would add them to my server through the terminal in a manner such as:

```
npm install react-dom --save-dev
```

This has worked for everything thus far, but I have run into JQuery keyframes. Normally JQuery and JQuery keyframes can be used by adding these script tags to your base html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='/path/to/jquery.keyframes[.min].js'></script>
```

Of these two, I cannot load in jquery keyframes via a plugin, so I thought that my only solution was to add the the jquery.keyframes.js file to my folders. I added this file to my main folder and added the script tag to my index.html:

```
<script src='.../jquery.keyframes.js'></script>
```

This is the part where I am getting confused. I began by getting the issue:

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/jquery.keyframes.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I read up on this issue, and eventually I was able to "fix" this issue by changing my script tag to:

```
<script src='.../jquery.keyframes.js' type="text/js"></script>
```

I'm really not sure if this is a proper fix. I am certainly still uncertain about my issue because when I try to use the command:

```
$.keyframe.define(aKeyframe);
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
```

This implies that I still haven't added the file correctly, or maybe I haven't imported properly into my JavaScript file. The only solutions I can see are:

1) The jquery.keyframes.js file should be in node_modules somewhere due to it being an extension of jquery which is there.

2) There was another way to fix the MIME type error.

3) I should have some import statement like:
    import $.keyframe from "../jquery.keyframe.js";

At the top of my JavaScript file.

Thank you in in advance for reading and submitting to this question.

Comment: I hate to be this guy but what is your motivation for using jQuery? It's generally considered bad practice to mix it with react since react uses a virtual dom and jQuery is built mostly around dom manipulation. That's not to say that it's impossible if you understand react lifecycle events but often times you can accomplish what you need in a simpler way with less bloat

Comment: I suppose my motivation is that jQuery seems to be much simpler to use, and there are a few things I don't know how to do with JavaScript. I assumed it would be simpler to fix this issue than to relearn animations with JavaScript, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There are ways to handle animations in React as well: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html I would suggest not using jQuery, in the long run it will save you from some frustration

Comment: Just to stress the point of not using JQuery with react - one of react greatest advantages is the virtual DOM, which assures that only elements that changed are rerndered. Manipulating the actual DOM in react is almost always an anti-pattern and just bad practice. Learning how to do things properly is always easier in the long run.